# How to subtract from the current timestamp the number of hours stored in a column?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, integer

I am trying to retrieve data from a column with integer values by getting the difference between the current_timestamp and the values in the column. This works in DB2 by simply stating the value as hour

```
TRANS_DATETIME > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - my_column_alias HOURS).
```

However using the same line in PostgreSQL returns the error below. Any ideas on how to modify query for PostgreSQL?

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - integer¶
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.¶

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please tell us what server you are using - various functions vary (greatly) from RDBMS to RDBMS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `make_interval()` to construct an interval from a given number of hours that's stored in a column:

```
trans_datetime > current_timestamp - make_interval(hours => my_column)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you soo much